# How to set placeholder first in Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

How can I set placeholders first and not the default value in Select2

I have this HTML code here:

```
<select class = "select2" style = "width:100%" id = "selectme">
     <option value = "oldest"> Person 1</option>
     <option value = "oldest"> Person 2</option>
     <option value = "oldest"> Person 3</option>
</select>
```

And Jquery for Select2 here:

```
$("#selectme").select2({
    placeholder: "Assign to:",
    allowClear:true
});
```

The example in [Select2 Documentation](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) works with setting placeholder as the default value first. But in my case the default value is Person 1 and not the placeholder. Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For placeholders to work properly you need a empty option to be added to the select list like:

```
<select class="select2" style="width:100%" id="selectme">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="oldest">Person 1</option>
    <option value="oldest">Person 2</option>
    <option value="oldest">Person 3</option>
</select>
```

<kbd>[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/palash/en3tt6uh/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<select class="select2" style="width:100%" id="selectme">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="oldest">Person 1</option>
    <option value="oldest">Person 2</option>
    <option value="oldest">Person 3</option>
</select>
```

jquery

```
$(".select2").select2({             
     placeholder: "change your placeholder"               
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html code does't seems right if its the original code you are not closing the tag:

```
<select class = "select2" style = "width:100%" id = "selectme"> 
 <option value = "oldest"> Person 1</option>
 <option value = "oldest"> Person 2</option>
 <option value = "oldest"> Person 3</option>
</select>
```